# Can Gazebo take advantage of dual GPUs in an NVIDIA GTX-690 system?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm looking at computer specs for a simulation computer, and considering either an NVIDIA GTX-680 or GTX-690 based video card.

The 690 offers twice the processing power, but is a dual GPU configuration.

Will the simulator be able to take advantage of this dual configuration?

NVIDIA had Ubuntu drivers for the system, so that isn't an issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/295/can-gazebo-take-advantage-of-dual-gpus-in-an-nvidia-gtx-690-system?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Physics simulation wise Gazebo doesn't have any GPU (or even CPU multi-threading) support at the moment. There used to be an optional implementation in Diamondback and the code is still there but it's not integrated and there don't seem to be any short-term plans of integrating it again. Bullet, which is planned to be supported by Gazebo by Feb 1 2013, seems to have GPU support though so in a few months you might be able to make use of your GPU. In terms of support you should check with Bullet but if the NVIDIA drivers work properly there shouldn't be an issue I guess.

Graphics wise Gazebo really doesn't need that much bam, but hopefully it will be able to run physics on GPU soon (and also get better graphics). As long as the drivers are well supported on Ubuntu including CUDA and OpenCL you should be good.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Max Pfingsthorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/103/max-pfingsthorn/) on 2012-11-29**:
There is GPU support for running range sensors though, right? At least there is API documentation about it. Is that running well?

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) on 2012-11-29**:
yea in theory there is a gpu laser, but at the moment it's not being used nor even compiled, so not sure whether it actually works (well).

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-11**:
Dual video cards are handled at the driver level, not the application level. As Gazebo integrates more GPU processing, it will automatically utilize the available GPU resources.